# Which parameter is pipe mapped to in bash or shell?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, sh

Ive got a script that formats the output of some log files that are hard to read, to make them human readable.  I call my script as follows

```
me@myHost $ cat superBigLogFile$date | grep "Stuff from log file I want to see" | /scripts/logFileFormatter
```

Inside the script, it uses $0, $1, and $2, but I dont know which parameter the cat'ed text is mapped to.   I want to make changes to the script, to where I only need to input the date and what I want to see.  Such as:

```
me@myHost $/scripts/logFileFormatter 2016-02-10 "Stuff I want to see"
```

Below are the details of the script.  The technical details are that this script formats the output of NDM logs, to a human readable form.

```
PATH=/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/bin
# add SUMM field and end of record marker on stat lines
awk '{print $0"|SUMM=N|EOR"}' |\
# format the STAT file, putting each field on a separate line
tr '|' '\012' |\
# separate times from dates and reformat source and destination file fields
# to have a space after the =
awk -F= '{
    if ($1=="DFIL" || $1=="SFIL") print $1 "= " $2
    else if ($1=="STAR" || $1=="SSTA" || $1=="STOP" ) {
      split($2,A," ")
      print $1 "=" A[1] "=" A[2]
    }
    else print
}' |\
# execute the ndmstat.awk that comes with Connect:Direct
awk -F= -f /cdndm/cmddbp1/cdunix/ndm/bin/ndmstat.awk |\
# additional formatting to remove the greater than sign arrows
sed 's/=>/=/g'
```

Comment: `$0`, `$1`, etc... isn't the shell. that's `awk`.

Comment: It's not a parameter. It's standard input.

Comment: The premise this question is based on is sufficiently false that I'm not sure it *can* be succinctly answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piping - the `|` - takes standard output of one command and "wires it" to the standard input of the other.

A simple script (let's assume it's called `script.sh`):

```
while read line
do
        echo "line" $line
done
```

Could work like this:

```
$ ls -al | ./script.sh
line total 15752
line drwxr-xr-x+ 106 kls staff 3604 Feb 10 23:13 .
line drwxr-xr-x 6 root admin 204 May 23 2015 ..
line -rwxr-xr-x 1 kls staff 56 Feb 10 23:13 a.sh
```

The key part here is a `read` command that reads from standard input and puts the result, line by line, in the `line` variable. This way each line gets printed (in an example above it's also prefixed with a "line" word, to differentiate it from a regular `ls -al` output) in a loop.

Now, I don't have a test data to run your script, but it'd be very similar with awk. Consider this script (saved to `script.sh`):

```
awk '{print $1}'
```

Can be invoked like:

```
$ ls -al | ./script.sh
total
drwxr-xr-x+
drwxr-xr-x
-rwxr-xr-x
```

Which shows that awk is indeed doing it's work - it would take and print the first token (`$1`) of each line of the output generated by `ls -al` (passed via standard input - `|`).

---

**Note on `$1` in Bash and Awk**

Important note: `$1` here is not a Bash variable - it's a variable defined within awk. It doesn't mean "first argument to the script" like it would in Bash, but rather "first token in the input". Those two are completely independent - this shows how to use both of them at the same time:

`script.sh`:

```
awk "{print \"$1 \" \$1}"
              ^       ^
              |       |
            Bash     Awk
```

Output:

```
$ ls -al | ./script.sh PREFIX       <-- We pass PREFIX now that
                                        will be bound to $1 Bash variable.
PREFIX total
PREFIX drwxr-xr-x+
PREFIX drwxr-xr-x
PREFIX -rwxr-xr-x
```

That might be a bit weird at first, so I added some comments in the code. Inspect double quotes closely, and how they are escaped with `\` sign. Similarly. the Awk `$1` is also escaped (`\$1`) while Bash' one is not.